# Роутинг и маршрутизация Laravel

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

После установки Laravel и создания проекта при обращении к корневому каталогу www.example.com запускается index.php где я подключил  файл index.php из папки public все нормально запускается стандартный роутер и берет темплейт "hello world". Но при попытке попасть в раздел www.example.com\home переадрессация не срабатывает а пытается попасть в папку home  получаю ошибку `The requested URL /home was not found on this server.`.

Почему не срабатывает роутинг Laravel?

Прикрепляю на всякий случай файл router.php

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

Быть может проблема в отсутствии .htaccess в корне сайта. Но я не знаю как он должен выглядеть.

Comment: HomeController с методом index - существует?

Comment: @zhenyab да существует, это коробочная версия laravel с сайта и их стандартные файлы.

Comment: .htaccess должен быть, без него, разумеется, роутинг работать не будет и он должен быть при инсталляции проекта создан. Он находится в папке public. И эта папка должна быть указана корневой в конфигурации сервера (apache/nginx). И еще: mod_rewrite должен быть включен

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вякий случай привожу пример стандартного .htaccess для Laravel, если используется apache:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**NB!** **mod_rewrite** должен быть включен

Comment: похоже на правду но выдает ошибку 500 в логах сервера написано что файл не найден. Htacces в самой папке public коректный но как должен выглядеть htaccess для доступа к \example\public\ (тут лежит индекс файл laravel )

Comment: о каком файле идет речь?

Comment: Прошу прощения , первую проблему решл заработал роутин в корень поместил .htaccess с путем к файлу в паблик . Теперь проблема что сервер не дает доступ к стилям что лежат в public/css выдает 400

Comment: URL к стилям какой?

Comment: http://example.com/css/app.css

Comment: покажите что в установках apache для данного сервера прописано